# MongoDB: How to concatenate document ids to a unique string

Tags: mongodb

Given a collections like this...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5546371e470000570184a633"), "name" : "John", "age": 31 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5546381e470000570184a634"), "name" : "Mike", "age": 35 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5546391e470000570184a635"), "name" : "Jack", "age": 28 }
```

... how do I merge the `_id` of all the guys older than 30? The result I'm looking for is

```
{ "_ids" : "5546371e470000570184a633,5546381e470000570184a634,5546391e470000570184a635" }
```

I could used `find` and then iterate over the result to concatenate the `_id`s... but perhaps the is a more convenient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any problem with your approach. Here is a slightly different one:

```
db.coll.distinct("_id", {age: {$gt: 30}}).map(function(el){
  return el.str;
}).join(",")
```

I do realize that all the _id are distinct by definition.